# SQL query to detect English strings that are bad for localization

Tags: localization, internationalization, translation

I am looking to build an SQL query that would detect strings that bad for localization, like strings that are used with concatenation, that contains bad placeholders or things like this.

Example:

- `Go to` - has a trailing space
- `Subscribe to` - to something, it should be a placeholder.
- anything not starting with an uppercase or number
- other... (feel free to come with ideas)

I am fully aware that **there is no perfect solution and** it's absolutely normal to get **false positives**.

Still, it is very useful to be compile a list of strings that should be investigated before sending these to translation.

Comment: I really do not think that will work... I would search for this in actual code. Although this probably cannot be done with regular expressions nor SQL statements. I'd go with lexical analysis or artificial intelligence. This is something really hard to detect :(

Answer (score 0):

I already have some conditions for doing this, here are:

```sql
SELECT text FROM strings WHERE
  text REGEXP '[[:<:]](of|per|as|with|to|from|at|with)\s*$' >= 1
  /* ending with a preposition*/

  OR (NOT text REGEXP '^[A-Z0-9{]') 
  /* starting with lowercase...?*/

  OR text LIKE '%{0}%'
  /* placeholders should be named not numbered */

  OR text REGEXP '\&(nbsp|gt|lt|amp|quot|tab|copy);'
  /* HTML entities should be escaped by the code, here we need only Unicode */

  OR text REGEXP '%[0-1\.\$\*][sdifFeEgGxXocpn)]'
  /* detect printf() placeholders */
```